# Нужно заполнить массив до определенного элемента

Tags: java, массивы

```
public class Battleship {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    settShips();

}
public static int choice_dir() {
    int rm_min = 1; //Горизонтальное направление
    int rm_max = 2; //Вертикальное направление

    int dir = 1; //rm_min + (int) (Math.random() * rm_max);
    return dir;
}
public static void settShips() {
    int FourPal = 1, ThreePal = 2, TwoPal = 3, OnePal = 4;
    int[][] field = new int[10][10];
    if (choice_dir() == 1 && FourPal >= 1) {
        int startDeploy4 = 0 + (int) (Math.random() * 5);
        for(int endDeploy4 = 4 + startDeploy4; endDeploy4 < startDeploy4; startDeploy4 = + 1) {
            for (int j = 0; j < field[startDeploy4][j+3]; j++) {
                field[startDeploy4][j] = 4;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Необходимо заполнить массив до определенного элемента массива (startDeploy4 + 4) в последнем цикле for
Всю голову уже сломал - никак не получается
Прошу помощи, господа

Comment: Вот этот цикл `for(int endDeploy4 = 4 + startDeploy4; endDeploy4 < startDeploy4; startDeploy4 = + 1)` никогда не выполниться, так как endDeploy всегда больше startDeploy (это ясно из этого места `int endDeploy4 = 4 + startDeploy4`). `startDeploy4; startDeploy4 = + 1` - такой синтаксис вообще впервые встречаю, честно говоря, думал что это не скомпилируется. Почему не написать просто `startDeploy4++`?

Comment: Можете привести пример как надо заполнять?